# Explain Shared Preferences for Different Checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I'm just starting to use shared preferences to allow me to save the state of a checkbox when leaving the application. I've gotten it to work but then it dawned on me that maybe it would save that preference for all checkboxes unless I make another preference. Do I have to make a shared preference for each checkbox to reference?

Code right now. I know that this will check or uncheck both checkboxes depending what I leave them at because they reference the same preference.

```
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.description);
    CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.description1);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean checked = sharedPref.getBoolean("checked", false);

    checkbox.setChecked(checked);
    checkbox1.setChecked(checked);
```

My check box handler looks like this

```
if(tmpChkBox.isChecked())
    {
        tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("checked", true).commit();

    }
    else
    {
        tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("checked", false).commit();
    }
```

So do I need to rename the string references within one shared preference? Like the `sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("checked", false).commit();` to make another one for a different check would I changed the "checked" to "checked1"?

Comment: Save the states with `putBoolean("checkbox1", checkbox1.isChecked());  putBoolean("checkbox2", checkbox2.isChecked());`. I leave it to you as exercise to retrieve the values and set the checkboxes state at start up.

Comment: @greenapps are you referring to within the handleCheckBoxClick method that I put the booleans? If that's the case I don't see why referring to all checkboxes within one method when I call it on every checkbox click would work well.

Comment: Why would you save the state in an on click handler for a checkbox? This was what you said: `to allow me to save the state of a checkbox when leaving the application`. Well you should do it indead when the application finishes.

Comment: I have multiple check boxes within an activity. I am trying to save the state of each of them individually. As it stands now if I click one and back out of the activity, going back all of them will be checked. I am trying to figure out how to have each state of the checkbox be saved independently. 

Where else would you save preference of being clicked or not if not in the checkbox handler?

Comment: How to store the state of each checkbox individually i already showed you for two checkboxes. You can do it for as many checkboxes in the same way. Just add a line for every checkbox. You should save all states in `onDestroy()` only.

Comment: I asked where that code would go and you didn't say. Also 'checkbox1.isChecked()' won't work since it is declared in my onCreate and I have a temporary checkbox when handling the onClick.

Comment: `asked where that code would go and you didn't say.` ??? In `onDestroy()` i said. Override it.

Comment: `I have a temporary checkbox`. No you have a temporary/local checkbox `variable`. Your checkbox is permanent. What you can do temporary in onCreate you could do in onDestroy too i think. Well you should do. Or make the variables private to the class.

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing out that technicality. I don't have any explicit onDestroy and won't carry on this lengthy comment discussion as its getting long and out of hand and not getting me anywhere.

Comment: If you followed my simple instructions you would exactly get where you were after. Your reaction is pretty strange.

Comment: @greenapps I'll ask one more time because I don't think you  understood the first time I asked. Where do I putBoolean? Your first response yielded an error because checkbox is out of scope within handleCheckBoxClick. Currently I am doing that within my handleCheckBoxClick.

Comment: Yes. And forget about your on checkbox click handler for a start. You only need that handler to change the color. But forget that handler first as it distracts from what you want. Instead add an @Override onDestroy() method to your class and put all code to save the checkbox state in it. Your variables will be out of scope if you had declared them in onCreate. But i already told you to declare them outside onCreate as private variables of your class. Or just declare new variables in onDestroy.